# Process a token from panel context in a ctools content type plugin

Tags: tokens, chaos-tool-suite

I have a ctools content type plugin. It has a simple text field settings form. In there I am putting a token from the panel content e.g. %vn_subject:vn-subject-facebook-link. I am then rendering this into a template. However, it is just rendering out the token as above without processing it. How can I process the token if possible to retrieve the required field value?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magic function is [ctools_context_keyword_substitute](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!ctools!includes!context.inc/function/ctools_context_keyword_substitute/7)

The key to getting this working is to make sure that you use the `all contexts` flag in your plugin configuration.

```
$plugin = array(
  'single' => TRUE,
  'title' => t('Instagram'),
  'category' => t('Content'),
  'all contexts' => TRUE,
);

/**
 * Render the custom content type.
 */
function MODULE_PANE_content_type_render($subtype, $conf, $panel_args, $context) {

  ....

  $replaced = ctools_context_keyword_substitute('your_string_with_%keywords', array(), $context);

  ....
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks @Letharion. I have that function and trying to implement but having some issues. What is $keywords? What format does $contexts have to be in. and what $converter_options are availables :)